# Windows Device Portal - Install App not visible

Tags: iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsondevices

I would like to add my UWP app to upboard2 device by Windows Device Portal, but in apps manager I don't see the Install App tab.

[image: Apps Manager]

The version of Iot core installed is 10.0.15063.0 and my windows 10 settings are in developer mode.

Any helps are appreciated
Many thanks,
emanuele

Comment: I've seen that before also, and I'm not sure what is causing it.  I haven't looked into it closely at all.

Comment: Thanks @Naikrovek. I solved this problem adding Install App in Options Menu -> Add Tools to workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem adding the tab **Install App**.

[image]

1. Click on **options menu**
2. Click **Add tools to workspace**
3. Check **Install App**

I hope it can helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You can mark this as the answer.